# keyboard short cut for switching between two or more instances of the same application?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, navigation

I'm wondering if there is a keyboard short cut for examining and switching between multiple windows of the same application?

I know of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> but that only shows different applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is the usual hotkey for that behaviour.

If it is not working for you, just type *shortcut* in Dash and open the keyboard settings. On the *Shortcuts* tab under *Navigation* you can set a hotkey for *Switch windows of an application*. (Or for *Switch windows of an app directly* if you like direct switching more.)

Comment: Ah ALT+` did the job! Very clear answer.